# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2015 Professional to Update 3 and it got stuck so i followed some advice on Google and reinstalled it and it still wouldn't work so then i repaired it and then when i tried to open a project it said that Visual C++ files were not loaded. How is that possible it download all MS Visual C++ .exe files and when i open new project there is nothing to open it with.

So I tried uninstalling it completely and it got stuck at "Creating system restore point". So i uninstalled all Visual Studio files via **Revo Uninstaller Pro**

So now I want to use Visual Studio 2015 again properly. What should i do? Buy a disk of the software or download it?

Comment: Download and try again. If it doesnt work it may be a problem with your computer. C++ works fine for me.

Comment: Avoid this update like the plague. It's the most buggy rubbish to come out of MS in ages. Even on a clean OS install, almost nothing works reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would try a few things:

1. I don't know about any after market uninstallers but I would go to the basic control panel and click on the ole 'Programs and Features'.  Find all instances of 'Microsoft Visual Studio Pro 2015' and uninstall them.
2. Whether you use a disk, a web installer, or the ISO you get from MSDN downloads.  You should ultimately get the ISO for reuse on a machine.  If you are using Windows 8 or higher there is a default ISO mounter finally.  I would attempt to reinstall only after all traces are gone of above.
3. I would NOT attempt to open an existing solution but create a new one to verify VS can operate as designed on the code you want.  If it can great, if not let's move on to a few more things it could be.
4. Under the 'Programs and Features' you should have 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable' ((x64) or (x86) or both).  If they are not there then during an install they were not chosen or an error occurred and they are needed I believe for C++ projects.  I would try to get it manually first here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51682.  If it does not install I would examine then if VS could create a C# or VB.NET solution and then narrow it down to being a C++ specific issue.  If the package installer is bombing out for some VS reason I would uninstall Redistributables and VS again and start from scratch.
5. If that does not work I would then start examining .NET Framework uninstalls for 4.6.1 and potentially 4.5.2 as well.  While the .NET should be secure if you were previously using a past version it could have some issues and you may be able to successfully reinstall it.  Typically VS install should notice the dependencies missing and you should not have to download these parts manually.  If not it is here (4.6.1 web installer): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981
6. Without knowing your specific errors and the amount of time invested I sometimes just reinstall an OS.  It is a very heavy handed method to fix things but you weight the time to troubleshoot, what your time is worth and how deeply you want to go down the rabbit hole with the issue.  If you absolutely have to fix the machine as it is, you would need more specific errors given to get a better more exact answer of what the error is throwing.  Typically you can go into Windows event logs and see the 'application' section and it will give errors typically thrown.

Some things to think about are if you are using an old OS to start with and if they have current patches.  Sometimes MS has a giant weave of product interchangeability that is more apparent as you develop for certain things.  Finding those dependencies is where MS truly fails at times.  They make things uber complex and cryptic for just installs, but have gotten worlds better since the 90's and 2000's at least.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed package errors by deleting this directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Visual Studio 2015 entirely off your system, getting to a specific Update is liable to be a pain. I found this link helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx

It says it works with Community and Professional as well, and indicates the parameters are for the web installer, but using them with the ISO also works.

Answer (score 0):

Download [release candidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3-rc) installer from Microsoft and run it. It will fail but then you can install actual update without problem.